# Can the set of integers $\Bbb Z$ be compactified (for example one point compactification) so that the new topology is metrizible?

Tags: general-topology

Can the set of integers $\Bbb Z$ be compactified (for example one point compactification) so that the new topology is metrizible ?

Comment: Yes: embed $\Bbb{Z}$ into $S^1$ by $$n \mapsto e^{2i \arctan n}$$.

Comment: It's harder to come up with a compactification that isn't metrizable than one that is...

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ is just a discrete infinite set, it's homeomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$, so you might as well ask it for that, and then it has the simple answer $\{\frac{1}{n}: n\geq 1\} \cup \{0\}$ (as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$).  But maybe you wanted a compactification which preserves more of the structure, or which has extra properties?

Comment: @Eric: Stone-Čech?